# My jquery slideshow is not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

Bear with me, I'm not a programmer. I have a [template based site](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com) from squarespace with a bad slideshow. The stock one scrolls too fast. So I turned off auto play in the settings.

Im able to add jquery / java / html / css but i cant change the existing code. Anyone have any suggestions on how to make this slideshow work properly?

Here is what I added to make it play/fade, but its really hurky-jerky.

```
<script>
window.setInterval(slideClick, 9000); function slideClick() 
{ $(".slide").click(); $(".sqs-active-slide").hide().fadeIn(); }
</script>
```

Comment: please provide the full jsfiddle

Comment: the what? This is all I have added. Im not sure how to find the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this maybe?
Make sure JQuery is included at top of page (I host mine myself but you can probably get the google hosting) It looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you put this at the bottom of page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slide").bind("click", function(){

        $(".sqs-active-slide").fadeOut(500, function(){
            //change active slide here
            //remove class from current active slide
            //then run the following line
            $(".sqs-active-slide").fadeIn(500);
        }); 

    }); 

    window.setInterval(slideClick, 9000); 
});

function slideClick() 
{ 
    $(".slide").click();
}
</script>
```

This will just stay on the same slide, so you have to add your code to go to the next slide, I can't guess what to do because you don't provide enough code.

EDIT:
The reason it wont work is because in my example you would have to change the $ for JQuery because your JQuery is configured that way
However, look for:

```
if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = jQuery('#slideshow span:last');
```

change the rest of the function after that line to:

```
var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : jQuery('#slideshow span:first');
$active.addClass('last-active');
$active.fadeOut(500, function(){
    $next.addClass('active').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: it still didnt work on my site, however it may work on someone elses.

Comment: That is why code should be posted in jsfiddle.net, we could provide a working example with code from your page. You could use something like firebug in firefox to extract the source code and then post that which is relevant.